# display the value of a variable that is modified several times

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know how to display the value of a variable that is modified several times, I tried with the future method but it does not work.

```
library(shiny)

# library(ipc)
# library(future)
# library(promises)
# plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("t")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  status <- reactiveVal({NULL})
  observe({
      status("beginning")
      # a function that takes a lot of time
      Sys.sleep(2)
      status("End")
  })

  # observe({
  #   future({
  #     queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("var", 0)
  #     Sys.sleep(2)
  #     queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("var", 1)
  #   }); NULL
  # })

  output$t <- renderText(status())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your approach will become difficult as shiny will first finish the code within `observe()` before updating the `renderText()`. But i think this might be of interest for you: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinybusy, https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html.

Answer (score 0):

This code increases `var' by 1 every two seconds.
This is what do you want to?

```
library(shiny)

# library(ipc)
# library(future)
# library(promises)
# plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("t")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  var <- reactiveVal(-1)


  # observer that invalidates every second. If timer is active, decrease by one.
  observe({
    invalidateLater(2000, session)
    isolate({
    var(var()+1)
      })
  })
  output$t <- renderText(var())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your help, sorry, I changed my code to remove the ambiguity, in fact var is rather used as a status.